# I want to get rid of the front gears on my Scott Aspect 740 2016, what size sprocket would fit the stock cranks

Tags: sprocket

I would like to know the cheapest sprocket but good quality to buy to single speed my stock Shimano FC-M300 crank set to get rid of the gears and go "1-by" so its a single speed just on the front.

Comment: Do you want to go single speed just on the front or on the rear as well?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. Specific product recommendations are off-topic here. See [The Tour](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) for more info. I've provided a generalized answer that should help you though.

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant your crank is a FC-M**T**300. That's a triple with 104/64mm BCD, symmetrical 4 bolt and 44/32/22 rings.

Any chainring that fits the 104mm BCD spider will work.

The cheapest option is to just keep the middle ring (you'll just need shorter chainring bolts if you take the outer ring off.)

Personally, as the 740 is only a 9 speed in the rear I would not ditch the large and small rings to make a 1x9, unless you live in a flat area or don't tackle hills and pretty much always ride on the middle ring anyway.

If you are thinking of swapping the rear derailleur, cassette and shifter as well, you will almost certainly be better off selling the 740 and buying a new bike that is designed as a 1x11 or 1x10.

Update:

There is currently FC-M**T**300 and FC-M300**0** cranks in Shimano's Acera range (as afar as I can tell from searching in their [line up docs](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/1.8/acera/3x9)). Either way they both have the same BCD and bolt pattern so the advice above is good.

Comment: And to confuse it even more, there's a Sunrace crankset called the FC-M300  which looks to be riveted together.  OP needs to check that he has chainring bolts and not rivets.

Comment: @Criggie I looked up the bike specs, it's def. a Shimano crank.

Comment: An alternative to shorter chainring bolts may be spacers that are the same thickness as the removed chainring. This spacers look like custom sized washers, usually made from aluminum. I mention that because the correct length chainrings may be hard to get in some locations, while suitable washers may do just fine.